# How can I compare a file with previous revision after moving the file to another folder and renaming it using svn?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a file in Rev 123, I move the file to another folder and do a commit.  Now I rename the page an do another commit.  Subversion seems to forget about the file, and I can only diff back to when I moved the file to another folder and renamed it.

I have to rename it, because the old name is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, uncheck the "Stop on copy/rename" checkbox in the log window.

If you're using the `svn` command I don't see this behavior.

If you're using some other SVN client, there must be some equivalent of the STop on copy/rename" option somewhere.

Comment: Wait, I think I am asking the wrong thing.  I'll update my question.

Comment: Yea, you are correct if I just rename the file. I updated my question my issue is with copying to another folder a file then trying to diff.

Comment: It should work as well, if you moved it using SVN, and not just with a standard move command. Using TortoiseSVN, drag and drop using the right mouse button instead of the left, and it will svn-move the file, allowing you to keep the history. Else, it's just seen by SVN as a delete and an add, without any relationship.

Comment: I think I found the gotcha in my situation.  I don't think VisualSVN is interpreting file moves from folder A to B as a svn-move.  Instead it is svn-add/svn-delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the new directory (where you moved it) and diff it as usually:

```
cd .../targetdir
svn -r124:123 theFileName.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use url to the target directory:

```
svn -r124:123 http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk/targetdir/theFileName.txt
```